# Graphing 2D coordinates, connecting them and creating a "spaghetti diagram" over a map

Tags: python, data-visualization

Let's say I have a bunch of 2D coordinates (x, y). I want to represent them over a map. Something like this:

[image: Coordinates]

Then I want to connect those coordinates creating a path like this:

[image: Path 1]

and more paths like that

[image: Path 2]

Then I would like to create a diagram showing every path and the most common areas like this (the blue path is the 'intersection' of both previous paths):

[image: Graph]

I don't really know where to start, some people say python and some libraries will do the job, others say that I'd may get into some data visualization tools. I'm seeking for some advice here. What would you use? How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define the lines by yourself, *i.e.*, which points connect to which (or some algorithm that can do that for you). After that you can use `matplotlib` library. Here is an example:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

>> x, y = np.random.random(size=(2,10)) # your logic on points that are connected goes here
>> x
array([0.60947809, 0.50267493, 0.22779167, 0.39017111, 0.7876591 ])
>> y
array([0.55613987, 0.08901633, 0.54394593, 0.38917903, 0.34158963])
>> for i in range(0, len(x), 1):
...  plt.plot(x[i:i+2], y[i:i+2], 'bo-')
>> plt.show()
```

[image]